# Where can I find source code of modules in `lib-dynload`?

Tags: python

Many built-in libraries use C implementations whenever possible.

For example, `heapq` uses `lib-dynload/_heapq.so` if it's available.

Where can I find source code of modules like `_heapq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the code for any version of CPython, go to:

- http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/

Replace the 3.3 with 3.2, 2.3, whatever for older versions. You can also explicitly put an hg revision number instead of a major.minor version, if you know what you're looking for.

The C modules are mostly inside the `Modules` subdirectory, and each one is generally named `foo.c` or `foomodule.c`, while the Python libraries are in the `Lib` subdirectory, named `foo.py`.

In the case of `heapq`, the actual `heapq` module is in Python (`Lib/heapq.py`), but it uses a C module named `_heapq` (`Modules/_heapqmodule.c`).

Of course you can also download the source. On the front page of http://python.org there are "Quick Links" for "Source Distribution" for the latest 2.x and 3.x versions, or you can click Download for all the other releases. The structure is, as you'd expect, the same thing you see at http://hg.python.org.

Answer (score 2):

Code for many C modules in the 3.3 release:
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Modules

Direct link to heapq source:
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Modules/_heapqmodule.c

Comment: That's specifically for the 3.3.0 release. You probably want `http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Modules/_heapqmodule.c` for the latest 3.3.x. You can just replace `3.3` with `3.2`, `2.7`, `2.3`, etc., for older versions, without having to know the hg revision.