# Where can I find the source code for the _tkinter module?

Tags: python, tkinter

According to the Python 3 documentation, Chapter 25.1: [tkinter - Python interface to Tcl/Tk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html):

> The Tk interface is located in a binary module named `_tkinter`. This
>   module contains the low-level interface to Tk

Where can I obtain the source code of this module?

I checked [`python/cython`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib/tkinter) on GitHub, but could not find it.

Comment: The source for _tkinter won't be very interesting, as it's just a wrapper for a tcl interpreter. What are you really looking for? If you're curious how widgets are actually constructed you'll want to look at the source code for tcl/tk.

Comment: @BryanOakley I can't speak for the OP but in my case, I am looking to extend the capability of the Canvas widget, which will require Tk and possibly Tkinter changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c) on GitHub for [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython)

Answer (score 4):

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924957/7952162) here which is related to your problem and gives this source (https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/) from python.org.

How did I get there? In python,

```
>>> import _tkinter
>>> _tkinter.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so'
```

Then in Google: "Python lib-dynload source".